# Populate java form with different objects

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to populate a form with different objects during runtime, depending on the values in a list of types (`mTypes` below). Initially, I am only considering 2 types (`JComboBox` or `JTextField`), but would later like to expand this to around 7 form-elements. My code so far creates and displays the dialog; **how should I initialize and collect the values?**

```
private String[] showInputDialog(String mTitle, String[] mTitles, int[] mTypes)  {
        // mTitle         --> Dialog Title
        // mTitles        --> Fields Titles (labels)
        // mTypes         1 - TextField
        //                2 - ComboBox      
        JDialog dialog = new JDialog(this, Dialog.ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        JLabel lblTemp;
        ArrayList<Object> mWidget = new ArrayList<Object>(); //widget to be textfield or combobox depending on int[] mTypes
        String[] RetValue = new String[mTitles.length]; //will hold and return the values in the different fields...


        JPanel pnlParent = new JPanel();
        pnlParent.setLayout(new BorderLayout(20, 20));
        lblTemp = new JLabel("  " + mTitle + "  ");
        pnlParent.add(lblTemp, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        lblTemp = new JLabel("   ");
        pnlParent.add(lblTemp, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        lblTemp = new JLabel("   ");
        pnlParent.add(lblTemp, BorderLayout.LINE_END);

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(mTitles.length, 2, 10, 10));
        pnlParent.add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        for (int i = 0; i < mTitles.length; i++) {
            lblTemp = new JLabel(mTitles[i]);
            lblTemp.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.LEFT);
            mainPanel.add(lblTemp);
            switch (mTypes[i]) {

                case 1: mWidget.add(new JTextField());
                        break;
                case 2: mWidget.add(new JComboBox());
                        break;
                default: //do something;
                        break;
                mainPanel.add(mWidget.get(i));
            }
        }
```

Comment: I am confused as to what the issue is. Does it pertain to your default case?

Comment: What do you mean by "recall the list mWidget".  Specifically, what do you mean by "recall"?  Also, given just the code you are showing, mWidget is completely unnecessary.  You should just add the item (textfield/combobox/etc) to the mainPanel directly

Comment: I don't know how to assign textfield once, or combobox whether the function is called with int mtype = 1 or 2

Comment: @RussellUhl, I don't know what the user would like to insert.. textbox or combobox... he just use 1 or 2 in the array mtypes, then the code should guess what to use. if I declare the variable widget to be a JTextField, and then I try to use JComboBox later, I will get a compile error...

Comment: Is the problem in populating the dialogue with values, or in collecting values? I interpreted that the problem only existed at collection-time (=recall) -- please comment if I am wrong.

Comment: @tucuxi, honestly, my problem is still in building the dialog.. because each time I call for it, I don't know if it will contain two textfields, or 1 textfield and 1 combobox, or maybe 2 comboboxes...

Comment: Ok - then the question is not clear at all. What problem is there in not knowing in advance what you will be building? Your code builds a dialogue, and the only thing that seems to be missing is to populate the fields with values, let the user change them, and then return the updated values. I suggest wrapping it in a JOptionPane to get blocking "cancel" and "accept" buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At some time, some kind of user action (a `confirm` button?) will cause the dialogue to return its contents. You would then execute something similar to this (assuming you use a `confirm` button, within its `actionPerformed` listener):

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    int i=0;
    for (Object o : mWidget) {
        if (o instanceof JTextField) { 
             retValue[i++] = ((JTextField)o).getText();
        } else if (o instanceof JComboBox) { 
             retValue[i++] = ((JComboBox)o).getSelectedItem(); 
        }
    }
}
```

You can use a common superclass of both `JTextField` and `JComboBox`: `JComponent`. That would leave you with an `ArrayList<JComponent> mWidget`, which looks a bit better.

Also note that this is *not* the cleanest way to do things. You could wrap those internal JTextField/JComboBox in subclasses that implemented, say, `MyWidget`, with the following definitions:

```
// MyWidget.java
public interface MyWidget {
     Object getValue();
}

// TextWidget.java
public class TextWidget extends JTextField implements MyWidget {
     // (add constructors here)
     public void setValue(Object value) { setText(value.toString()); }
     public Object getValue() { return getText(); }
}

// ComboWidget.java
public class ComboWidget extends JComboBox implements MyWidget {
     // (add constructors here)
     public void setValue(Object value) { setSelectedItem(value); }
     public Object getValue() { return getSelectedItem(); }
}
```

This would allow you to declare an `ArrayList<MyWidget>`, no longer requiring the use of casts or `instanceof` when you need to collect all results.

Comment: You've helped alot @tucuxi ... I will look into your code, and have a second thought.. actually, It's not only about textbox and combobox.. but another 7 types of stuff..  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Then you would do well to wrap them all up in a common interface, so that you do not need to use any instanceof detection. Also, please think of clarifying your original question and/or upvoting helpful answers, so that others looking for answers can also benefit.

Comment: I wasn't able to explain the question very well... but you answered exactly what I needed !!!  :)